# How do we install yaafe on linux?

Tags: python, cmake

I've been trying to install Yaafe Library on my linux system, but I'm unable to do it as I can't compile the yaafe source using ccmake. Does anyone have the detailed step-by-step procedure for the same?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow the instructions, which failed for me during compile. The `ccmake` can be replace by `cmake`. I could not install `libhdf5-serial-1.8.4`, because it was integrated in the main package.

#### Alternative approach

An alternative to yaafe would be [librosa](https://github.com/bmcfee/librosa), which has the advantage of being available via PyPi. You install it via (assuming Debian/Ubuntu)

```
apt-get install pip
```

(for the PyPi client), and

```
pip install librosa
```

if you follow their advice and install `scikits.samplerate`, you also need `libsamplerate0-dev`:

```
apt-get install libsamplerate0-dev
```

Comment: use `sudo` in ubuntu, place it before the commands (as in `sudo apt-get ...`)

Answer (score 0):

The home page of the library includes a [thorough manual for compiling yaafe](http://yaafe.sourceforge.net/manual/install.html). 
I am citing the beginning here:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install cmake cmake-curses-gui libargtable2-0 libargtable2-dev libsndfile1 libsndfile1-dev libmpg123-0 libmpg123-dev libfftw3-3 libfftw3-dev liblapack-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libhdf5-serial-1.8.4

 $ mkdir build

 $ cd build
 $ ccmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<lib-path> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install-path> ..
```

see the rest there.

Comment: what path do i give in <lib-path> and <install-path> in the fourth step?

Comment: I did the same, didn't get the post-installation files, I was suppose to get in the directory where i did make and make-install.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I had to do in Ubuntu 14.04 to get it working:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y 
sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev

sudo apt-get install cmake cmake-curses-gui libargtable2-0 libargtable2-dev libsndfile1 libsndfile1-dev libmpg123-0 libmpg123-dev libfftw3-3 libfftw3-dev liblapack-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libhdf5-7
```

Download Yaafe from here:https://github.com/Yaafe/Yaafe/archive/master.zip

Extract Yaafe-master.zip

Inside Yaafe-master directory:

```
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake ..
make
sudo make install

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/
```

Also add this path to your IDE (Enviromental Variables) if yaafe does not work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed it using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_unix), and it was extremely easy!  Just install Anaconda like the link tells you to.  On the last step, I recommend you allow Anaconda to modify your `PATH` so that when you type `python` on the command line, it uses the Anaconda version of Python.  Then restart your terminal, just to make sure it's using the Anaconda stuff you just installed.

Then, assuming you're using Ubuntu, you just need to type the following command:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/Yaafe yaafe
```